# What is the difference between 元気 and 元氣?

Tags: kyūjitai-and-shinjitai

Also can you explain what each kanji character means?

Comment: on [http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp](http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp) 元気 and 元氣 are the same thing I just wondered of the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kanji 氣 is an old alternative form of 気. You may see this kanji in calligraphy arts, historical documents and such, but in modern usage this word is always 元気.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had no idea I was looking at such an old character.

Comment: @Sam It's not -that- old, it was official until 1946.

Answer (score 2):

Modern Chinese differentiates between Traditional (Taiwan, Hong Kong, etc) and Simplified characters (mainland). One might assume that Japanese Kanji and Traditional Chinese are the same thing; not so. The Japanese have made a number of their own simplifications. Here are a few examples of Kanji that are considered "archaic" by Japanese standards, but are the everyday form used in Traditional:

> [氣]{hei3}→[気]{き}
>
> [學]{hok6}→[学]{がく}
>
> [貓]{maau1}→[猫]{びょう} (previously みょう, previously めう)
>
> [國]{gwok3}→[国]{こく}

For instance, the word for weather in Cantonese is [天氣]{tin1 hei3}. Look familiar? :)

Comment: Citation needed: *"Many Japanese speakers think that Japanese Kanji and Traditional Chinese are the same thing; "*  I think you'd be hard pressed to find a native speaker or advanced learner suffering under the belief that contemporary Japanese characters are the same as traditional Chinese characters.

Comment: Many non-Japanese/Chinese speakers think that Japanese Kanji and Traditional Chinese are the same thing の間違いじゃないのｗ

Comment: Redacted. I didn't like the line of first writing either.